# Is it safe to override SaveChanges and SaveChangesAsync like this?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I have some custom logic that is performed around the `SaveChangesAsync` method. The problem is that I have some legacy code that calls `SaveChanges` instead. I have determined that the code below could be fine, but I'm afraid of any possible side-effect (deadlocks). I have had problems trying to turn asynchronous calls into synchronous calls.

```
class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        BeforeSaveChanges();
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await DispatchDomainEvents();
        return result;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the original `SaveChanges` look like?

Comment: No, for many reasons. For starters, it's always a bad idea to block an async method to make it "synchronous".  That `SaveChanges` method doesn't seem to be doing anything useful. The other reason has to do with the extra methods. What do they do? A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, Its job is to cache all changes in a bounded context and persist all of them at once. `DispatchDomainEvents` isn't a UoW or Repository concern. That DbContext will have to know and get tied to classes that have little to do with its job

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L479

Comment: `I have had problems trying to turn asynchronous calls into synchronous calls.` don;t do that to begin with

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to implement SaveChanges the same way you implemented the async version, by calling the base method inbetween your own method calls?

Comment: What about modifying your existing code to use the async version? Then call GetAwaiter().GetResult() on top level calls that you can't make asynchronous. Note that almost all entry points can be made asynchronous these days.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Then I would have duplicate code. Moreover, the DispatchDomainEvents is async.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The DbContext is the perfect place to dispatch domain events. It's exactly it who controls the transactionality of the mutation and tracks the entities, so yes, it's its concern. In addition to that, a DbContext is not a multi-entity unit of work, but a unit made of unit of work + repositories.

Comment: @SuperJMN you asked what the problems are. People already explained the obvious problems but you refuse to acknowledge them even though you `have had problems trying to turn asynchronous calls into synchronous calls`.  There's no duplication because the two methods are fundamentally different. Sync vs async is a **serious** difference. The reason you have to write the event dispatch code twice is that it's used in the wrong place, inside the wrong abstraction. The code that controls transactions is the code that calls `DbContext.Dispose()` and `DbContext.SaveChanges/Async()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, so, where's the code that disposes the DbContext in an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: @SuperJMN you write that code. When you call `SaveChanges` in an action method. When you *don't* call that method, letting DI dispose the scoped DbContext as it goes out of scope. If anything, that's an argument *against* what you try to do here. The code that knows what to do is the action, not the DbContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should copy the same implemenetation in the sync `SaveChanges` method:

```
class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        BeforeSaveChanges();
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await DispatchDomainEvents();
        return result;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        BeforeSaveChanges();
        var result = base.SaveChanges();
        DispatchDomainEvents().Wait(); // Ideally, you should have a sync version for this method too
        return result;
    }
}
```

Blocking the current thread to wait for an async method to finish may lead to thread starvation in some scenarios.